# Interface of todo app breaking only in chrome browser, on refresh

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, css-grid

This is a simple todo app built with react, bulma, and css grid. When I reload the page in chrome the height of the input form changes from 385x27.27 to 385x58.45, and lowers itself to the point of breaking through the bottom boundary of my css grid. I don't think this has much to do with my react code since I tested my app in firefox and edge which did not have this issue.

I also tried clearing my cache, cookies etc. for chrome which did not fix the issue. Surprisingly as soon as you type something into the input box (just typing) it fixes itself to the proper proportions. But as soon as you refresh, it breaks again. I should also note that it's broken on first render of the page (not just refreshing).

I suspect it has to do with my grid and how I wrapped the html elements (I'm still learning), or maybe event.prevent.default() and .reset() inside my react code are interfering with grid? I'm really not sure, and without error messages this has been hard to troubleshoot. I included the full code for my app below and images of the problem.

Page first loaded or refreshed (broken)

[image: Page first loaded]

Page after typing "p" into the input (correct)

[image: Page after typing "p" into the input]

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';



/* InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method. */
const InputTaskForm = ({ formValidation }) => { 
    return (                                      
      <form name="charlie" className="charlie" onSubmit={formValidation}>
        <input name="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Task..." size="35"/> 
        <button className="button is-info is-small" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
}

const DisplayTasks = ({ tasksArray, removeTask, crossOutTask }) => { 
  return (
    <div id="orderedList">
      <ol>

        {/* Create our list items and corresponding buttons by mapping over the tasks array. The array is currently made up of objects with a title and crossedOut key. Therefore keep in mind the task prop is carrying objects, not the task title itself */}
        {tasksArray.map((task, index) => (                            
          <li onClick={ () => crossOutTask(index) } key={index} >

            {/* Check the crossedOut value of the current task object. If crossedOut is true display it crossed out, else display it uncrossed */}
            { task.crossedOut                                         
              ? <strike>{task.title}</strike> 
              : task.title }

            <button className="removeButton button is-danger is-small" onClick={ event => removeTask(event, index) } >Remove</button>
          </li>
        ))}

      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};



class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userinput: '',
    tasksarray: [],                               
  }


/* ============================================== #FUNCTIONS ============================================== 
=========================================================================================================== */
formValidation = event => {                                       // event prop passed from InputTaskForm component
  event.preventDefault();                                         // prevent form from auto-refreshing on submit
  const userInput = event.target.userinput.value                  // userInput stored
  const userInputIsBlank = userInput.trim().length < 1            // trim (remove) prefixed and affixed spaces, then check length

  userInputIsBlank 
    ? alert(`Error: invalid submission`) 
    : this.storeTask(userInput);
};

storeTask = userInput => {                                         // userInput passed from formValidation function
    this.setState({
      userinput: userInput,
      tasksarray: [...this.state.tasksarray, { title: userInput, crossedOut: false } ] //create a copy of tasks array then add a new object into the array filled out with user input
    });
    document.forms["charlie"].reset();
};


removeTask = (event, index) => {                                    // props passed from DisplayTasks component
  event.stopPropagation();                                          // prevents bubbling to crossOutTask in the DisplayTask component
  const removedTaskArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];              //removedTaskArray is just a copy of our current array for the moment

  removedTaskArray.splice(index, 1);                                //here removedTaskArray actually becomes an array w/ the removed task (removed with splice)                 
  this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTaskArray });   
};


crossOutTask = index => {                                           // index prop passed from DisplayTasks component
  const { tasksarray } = this.state
  const selected = tasksarray[index];

  this.setState({                                           
    tasksarray: [                                                   // change tasksarray state to: [prior slice, change, after slice]
      ...tasksarray.slice(0, index),                                // slice off (copies) of array elements prior to index element
      Object.assign(selected, {crossedOut: !selected.crossedOut}),  // invert the selected line's crossedOut value
      ...tasksarray.slice(index + 1)                                // slice off (copies) of array elements after index element
    ]
  });
};


componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.tasksarray);                               // debugging :) 
};


/* =============================================== #RENDER ================================================ 
=========================================================================================================== */
  render() { 
    const { tasksarray } = this.state
    const { formValidation, storeTask, removeTask, crossOutTask } = this

    return (
      <div className="grid-container">

        <div className="input-tasks-container box">
          <h1 className="title is-4">Todo: </h1>
          <InputTaskForm 
            task={storeTask}
            formValidation={formValidation} />
          </div>

        <div className="tasks-grid-container">
          <h1 className="Tasks-title title is-4">Tasks</h1>
          <h1 className="Tasks-title subtitle is-6">Tip: click on a task to mark it as done</h1>
            <DisplayTasks 
              tasksArray={tasksarray} 
              removeTask={removeTask} 
              crossOutTask={crossOutTask} />
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    };
};


/* ================================================ #EXPORT =============================================== 
=========================================================================================================== */
export default App;
```

App.css

```
/* Prevent highlighting when double clicking list items */
#orderedList {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */    
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 425px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
}

.input-tasks-container {
  margin-top: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.Tasks-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.tasks-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.removeButton {
  margin-left: 10px
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.charlie {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ol {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: try removing `.charlie {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}`

Comment: @JuniusL. That is something I tried before making the post. Did not fix the issue.

Comment: what about `.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 425px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
}`?

Comment: @JuniusL.Yes, when I delete .grid-container the issue goes away, although of course, so does most of my grid/layout. Edit: After trying what you suggested I tried switching out the pixeled column/row for pure fr units, and the problem doesn't show up. So it looks like having the third column and first row in pixels is causing the problem, but why?